# How to use (top) margin with CSS3 drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, margin, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down menu completely in CSS3. For the most part I have accomplished what I wanted, but for some reason I can't seem to add `margin-top: 10px;` to drop down menu, as I don't want it touching the main link. It seems to deactivate the hover when it hits the margin?

I have posted a working example with no margin on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5QSv/

This is with the `margin-top: 10px;`, and does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/RastaLulz/J5QSv/2/

As you can see, that works perfectly fine. However, when you uncomment `margin-top: 10px;` it no longer works.

Do you know a way to fix this? or a work around?

HTML

```
<span class="LinksMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Account</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #F3F3F3;
}

a:link,a:visited { color:#000; text-decoration:none }
a:hover,a:active { color:#000; text-decoration:underline }

.LinksMenu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    clear: both;
}

.LinksMenu ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.LinksMenu li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.LinksMenu ul ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 0;
    color: #000;
}

.LinksMenu ul ul {
    /* margin-top: 3px; */
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.LinksMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine here. Chrome(latest) on win XP. (I know...) Which browser are you testing in? Also in your fiddle it's `margin-top: 3px;` I changed it to 30 and works perfectly.

Comment: Tested in firefox 8.0 and is working fine.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome on a Mac. Did you uncomment the margin part, then run it? I've tried both Safari and Chrome, and I can not scroll over the sub links (they disappear). http://jsfiddle.net/RastaLulz/J5QSv/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fix is to add height to the hovered element on hover, so the element is underneath the one that appears. You'll need to add a class to the top level `<li>`s.

```
.LinksMenu ul li.myClass:hover{
    height: 80px;
}
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5QSv/3/).

Comment: if the parent list has a background and border it ugly http://jsfiddle.net/J5QSv/25/

Comment: Well that's up to your stylistic choices. There are a great number of ways to make things not "ugly."