# Drop down menu with margin-top

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a drop down menu with margin-top. The problem is, when I go with my mouse from li to drop down, it closes. How can I make it work with margin-top?

http://jsfiddle.net/wGzj8/8/

From my real design:

[image: Drop down]

I've tried this solution: [How to use (top) margin with CSS3 drop down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322663/how-to-use-top-margin-with-css3-drop-down-menu) , but it moves the image under my ul down ("O fakulteti").

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you wrap your sub menu with extra `<div>`? This `<div>` should have `margin-top: 4px` style instead of the same style you had for nested `ul`:

```
<li>
    <div class="header_meni_crta"></div>
    <a class="header_glavni_a">O fakulteti</a>
    <div style="margin-top: 4px;">
        <ul style="display: none;" class="dropdown_levo" style="margin-top: 0;">
            <li><a href="#">Vizitka</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vodstvo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Organi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Zaposleni</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Organiziranost in enote</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Akti in pravilniki</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wGzj8/18/

Comment: Hi, the drop down now works correctly, but this happens to my design: (http://oi45.tinypic.com/pvxmx.jpg)

Comment: I've added margin-top: -4px; on my image, so it went up and it now works great. All the answers were correct, but I've chosen this one as correct because it was first. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Add following code of `margin-bottom` in the selector,

```
#header_glavni_meni ul li .header_glavni_a {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the same thing happens like on the image I've commented with on the first answer.

Comment: Hmm, see if adding a negative margin to your image puts it back in place.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the top level list elements a little taller so they overlap the area between the margin that is causing the issue, you can add a bottom padding of 4px to achieve this. Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wGzj8/22/

Answer (score 0):

This should help you : http://jsfiddle.net/seyfollahi/qwL8P/

add height in : `#header_glavni_meni ul li .header_glavni_a {}`

change margin-top in :  `#header_glavni_meni ul li ul {}`