# Css drop down/up menu with margin bottom

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've got a simple dropdown css menu, which is positioned in the footer and with upwards direction - fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RmTpc/11/

i would like for opened menu to have some bottom margin from the main li ("Items"), but when i apply `margin-bottom: 30px` to the `ul.dropdown ul`, opened menu dissapears on hover.

I've googled and also tried answers from stackoverflow:

[Drop down menu with margin-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042471/drop-down-menu-with-margin-top)

[How to use (top) margin with CSS3 drop down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322663/how-to-use-top-margin-with-css3-drop-down-menu?lq=1)

but can't get it to work. Any help appriciated, thanks :)

EDIT: Sorry, posted wrong fiddle before, updated the link above.

Comment: Remove `margin-bottom` from `ul.dropdown ul`

Comment: If i do, opened menu sticks to the li. Want to get it to have some clearing, with margin or padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the margin - it's effectively 'dead space' so you're not actually touching it when you move the mouse up towards it.

I think the best solution is to remove the margin, and add the 30px to the bottom padding of the `ul` (so you're touching it when you mouseover), and remove the background color:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 20px 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/RmTpc/3/)

You'll probably need to adjust the padding of the list items to make up for the lost background space, but this solution should work for you.

EDIT:

Using the updated JSFiddle, you'll need to move your borders to the 'li' elements as well. See the [New JSFiddle I set up](http://jsfiddle.net/RmTpc/14/), or this code:

```
ul.dropdown ul {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 20px 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #bbb;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.dropdown ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid #bbb;
}
ul.dropdown ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know, can't find a proper solution. So far only margin makes the clearing, but disables the hover.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it a bit clearer - is it working for you now?

Comment: Yep, your solution works well. I've screwed up, because i've posted wrong fiddle :/ Correct one is: http://jsfiddle.net/RmTpc/11/ (also updated in question)

Comment: Ah, so the problem's with the borders now. Switch them to the list items and you should be fine (updated my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following **CSS**:
http://jsfiddle.net/RmTpc/15/

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
    z-index: 999;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
ul#nav {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    font-weight: 300;
}
ul.dropdown, ul.dropdown li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.dropdown {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    min-height: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 600;
}
ul.dropdown ul {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
    zoom: 1;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
    background: #fff;
    border-left: solid 2px #bbb;
    border-right: solid 2px #bbb;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
ul.dropdown ul li:first-child {
    border-top: solid 2px #bbb;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
ul.dropdown ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: solid 2px #bbb;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.dropdown ul ul {
    left: 99%;
    top: 1px;
}
ul.dropdown-upward ul {
    bottom: 100%;
    top: auto;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover, ul.dropdown li.on {
    color: #bbb;
}
ul.dropdown a:link, ul.dropdown a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
ul.dropdown a:active {
    color: #FFA500;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Your menu will look like you have done it so far. One difference is that I replaced the `margin` with `padding`.

**UPDATE:** I have updated the CSS Code

Comment: Thanks - works good, but i've posted wrong fiddle, correct one is: http://jsfiddle.net/RmTpc/11/

Answer (score 0):

Put the `margin-bottom: 30px` in the `ul.dropdown ul li` block and not for `ul.dropdown ul`. I think that'll make it work.